# Perl: best way to do longest prefix match (string)

Tags: perl, longest-prefix

I have a list of around 5000 words. I want to find the longest prefix match among those words for a given word. For example, in my list I have :

```
1
121
12234
20345
21345
```

Now If I search for 12134 the result will be 121 (longest match). I know it can be done in different ways. But, what should be the most efficient way ?

Comment: If you only have 5000 words in your list, I wouldn't worry too much about efficiency.  Any reasonable approach will find the match in a tiny fraction of a second.   You can find a list of options [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=305753).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @prefixes = qw(
    1
    121
    12234
    20345
    21345
);

my $num = '12134';

my ($longest) = sort { length $b <=> length $a } grep { 0 == index $num, $_ } @prefixes;

print "$longest\n";
```

Outputs

```
121
```

Comment: isnt the <=> operator used for sorting numbers? in my case I may also have chars in my list like 1#55 etc.

Comment: That's because it's comparing the length of the match, not the match itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the regex engine to do this for you. It should be very fast

I hope it's obvious that the regex pattern needs to be built only once, and can then be used to find the longest prefix for any number of target strings

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @prefixes = qw/
    1
    121
    12234
    20345
    21345
/;

my $target = 12134;

my $re = join '|', sort { length $b <=> length $a } @prefixes;
$re = qr/(?:$re)/;

say $1 if $target =~ /^($re)/;
```

#### output

```
121
```

---

#### Update

Alternatively, the `Tree::Trie` module can be used to implement the trie search that the regex engine provides like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Tree::Trie;

my @prefixes = qw/
    1
    121
    12234
    20345
    21345
/;

my $target = 12134;

my $trie = Tree::Trie->new({ deepsearch => 'prefix' });
$trie->add(@prefixes);

say scalar $trie->lookup($target);
```

The output, of course, is the same as that of the previous code

Comment: This may slow down [somewhere around 6,553 prefixes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29217346/176646) but should be fine for the OP's ~5,000.