# Is there any limitation to make the `|` condition inside the regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I have the below code

```
$regex_data = "pattern|pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5|pattern6";  

my $data = "This line has some pattern";

if($data=~m/$regex_data/i)
{
    print "Data matched with pattern\n";
}
```

In my above code `$regex_data` has the all possible pattern separated by `|`. I'm working with future project and then I don't know the limit of the pattern. So the  `$regex_data` was directly implemented to the regex matching. Now it is working ( for small set of pattern 1..100). And my doubt Is there any problem will occur on large set of pattern in regex.?

```
$regex_data = "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5|pattern6|pattern7|pattern8|pattern9|pattern10|pattern11|pattern12|pattern13|pattern14|pattern15|pattern16|pattern17|pattern18|pattern19|pattern20|pattern21|pattern22|pattern23|pattern24|pattern25|pattern26|pattern27|pattern28|pattern29|pattern30 .. and so on ";
```

Comment: What do you mean by "limitation"?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I'm trying to know, The regex will support the only n-number `|` or there is not an issues to make the n-number of `|`

Comment: No, there's no real limit. Although you will find efficiency starts to become a problem as you get really large.

Comment: why could't not use the pattern in arrays list?

Comment: @ssr1012 Array  list means? split the pattern by `|` and loop through the array then check the pattern into data. Are you telling like that?

Comment: Yes. May be this will easier to grep the datas.

Comment: See [Why does adding one more alternative make my regex over 600 times slower?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217346/why-does-adding-one-more-alternative-make-my-regex-over-600-times-slower)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Thanks. I wonder if that has been fixed. Disabling the optimisation if it requires a `longjmp` seems like a temporary hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, the only practical limit on the length of an alternation is the amount of memory it occupies

The regex engine compiles an alternation into a *trie* structure, and I would guess that expanding the string into a list of alternatives would occupy *more* memory than the compiled regex

On the other hand there is a big speed disadvantage to the alternative of a Perl loop

- The *trie* algorithm will be much faster than a simple iterative comparison
- The regex engine is written in C, which is generally much faster than Perl code
- The Perl loop must perform a separate regex compilation on every segment of the list

Here's a simple benchmark which you may want to enhance to a more representative data set. Using the alternation directly as a regex is faster by a factor of 2.5

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Benchmark 'cmpthese';
use List::Util 'any';

my $regex_data = 'pattern|pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5|pattern6';

my $re = qr/$regex_data/i;

my $data = "This line has some pattern";

cmpthese(-10,{
    loop  => sub { any { $data =~ /$_/ } split /\|/, $regex_data },
    regex => sub { $data =~ $re },
});
```

#### output

```
          Rate  loop regex
loop  134375/s    --  -60%
regex 338449/s  152%    --
```

Answer (score 0):

If by unknown limit you mean unknown number of alterations, you can use the `qr` operator to add them one at a time. If `@patterns` contain the list of alternatives:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $re = qr{ \Q$patterns[0]\E }x;
for ( @patterns[1..$#patterns] ){
    $re = qr{ $re | \Q$_\E }x;
}
say Dumper $re;
```

See [perldoc -f qr](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) for more details.

Answer (score -2):

You may use arrays list

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $regex_data = "pattern|pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5|pattern6";  

my @arrays = split/\|/, $regex_data;
my $data = "This line has some pattern";
if (grep { $data=~ /\b$_\b/} @arrays) 
{
    print "Data matched with pattern\n";
}
else
{
    print "Not matched...\n";
}
```

Comment: My regex patterns are fetching from DB. DB has the patterns, which are separated by `|`. So I'm trying to use the pattern without any modification. Or else I need to split the data using `|`. Then will make the grep.

Comment: `grep` is a bad choice in this scenario, as it's inefficient - it'll match _every_ pattern against _every_ element. `regex` will bail out when it finds a first match.

Comment: @ssr1012 @Sobrique was correctly said. I don't want to search into the whole pattern. That the reason I didn't use the `g` modifier in my regex. grep will search onto the whole array.