# Laravel query with regexp performance improvement

Tags: php, regex, pagination, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel 5.3.
I have a big table (1.2 million rows).

there is a text column named comment.
I wrote this query -

```
$regexp = 'good | bad | nice';

$temp1 = $connection->table('table1')
                ->select('*')
                ->where('comment', 'NOT REGEXP', $regexp)
                ->paginate(30);
```

$regexp contains nearly 500 words.
Because this table size is big, query takes significantly more time.
The reason is that first filtering is applied on whole table then 30 rows are getting returned.

Is there a way to reduce the time, filter only 30 rows and return.

Comment: If you don't need pagination, see "skip/take" here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: Are you storing multiple values as CSV in this column?

Comment: @Mike I checked skip/take but I need pagination.

Comment: @Viney No, storing simple text data.

Comment: it is not using any index so query optimiser properly do nothing. To improve performance you will need to build search index, you can find more about `information retrieval`

Comment: You are trying to use MySQL for what it's not designed to do. Specifically you are trying to treat it as a full-text search engine. You better utilise a better software for that such as Elastic Search, Sphinx, or Solr. If you still want a MySQL solution, you better compose a secondary index and maintain it by application. Secondary index in this case will be a separate table. This solution has drawbacks not to say it's not always applicable. And that's nothing to do with Laravel, of course.

Comment: Is your regex hard-coded into your script like that, or does it come from user input? If it's hard-coded, you could alter your table and add an extra column indicating whether it matches your regex. You just have to re-run it on all columns whenever you update the regex, and update that row if you're editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest performance hog is your regex pattern: ~500 alternations is bad.
The following post will give you an idea how just one extra alternation can cause a massive slow-down: [Why does adding one more alternative make my regex over 600 times slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217346/why-does-adding-one-more-alternative-make-my-regex-over-600-times-slower)

The general suggestion is, break down your alternations into smaller chunks and optimize your patterns separately.

A simple tool to optimize regex patterns is Perl's [Regexp::Optimizer](http://search.cpan.org/~dankogai/Regexp-Optimizer-0.23/lib/Regexp/Optimizer.pm). However, do not expect wonders. Handwritten patterns are much better. 
Tip: [myregextester.com](https://myregextester.com/index.php) allows you optimizing patterns online.

Another thing to think of is having a proper index for your searches. However, I doubt this will save your cake. What you really want is a full-text search engine, as suggested.