# regex runtime diff between create a new rule and using "|", python

Tags: python, regex

I am using `python3`.

I have one rule: `(re.compile(r'a b', re.IGNORECASE), "A")` and later I found `'a c'` should also be a match.

Which way is more efficient to add this rule?

```
(re.compile(r'a (b|c)', re.IGNORECASE), "A")
```

or simply add another rule

```
(re.compile(r'a c', re.IGNORECASE), "A").
```

I did 'timeit', yet no significant difference. I am wondering my conclusion is right or not, the reason behind it and if it applies to multi-case, such as 'a (b|c|d|e)' and three extra rules.

Comment: What's a "rule"?

Comment: I mean the pattern, re.compile(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general answer, the performance outcomes greatly depend on the regex engine/flavor that is used. For instance, Perl is known to be very sensitive to [regex alternatives](http://snowplow.org/martin/rebench/), e.g. see [Why does adding one more alternative make my regex over 600 times slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217346/why-does-adding-one-more-alternative-make-my-regex-over-600-times-slower)

Python's re module is not the quickest (not at all), however, [performance comparisons suggest](http://snowplow.org/martin/rebench/) it is less affected by regex alternatives.

On the other hand, it seems that python's re performance suffers more [Catastrophic Backtracking from Runaway Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).
For instance, a pattern of the form `x+` performs better when it is written as `xx*`.

In general, it is recommended to use Possessive Quantifiers, Atomic Grouping (see link above), and [Capture Only When Necessary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices) to improve the regex run-time.

In consequence, it is often much more efficient to test for each regular expression separately than to use an alternate regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

As a regular expression is matched in linear time (w.r.t. to input word), I believe that it should be more efficient to have one single (more complex) regular expression than a lot of different (smaller) ones.

A quick-and-dirty test:

```
import re 
import timeit

def create_simple_regex(lookup):
  return re.compile(lookup)

def create_complex_regex(lookups):
  return re.compile('|'.join(lookups))  

def look_with_simple(lookups, word):
  return [create_simple_regex(lookup).findall(word) for lookup in lookups]

def look_with_complex(lookups, word):
  return create_complex_regex(lookups).findall(word)

lookups = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
word = 'hello world!' * 1000

print(timeit.timeit('look_with_simple(lookups, word)', number=1000, globals=globals()))

print(timeit.timeit('look_with_complex(lookups, word)', number=1000, globals=globals()))
```

This leads to (executed in an online REPL):

```
1.62659708800129
5.003811294998741
```

So it seems I was wrong ;-)

Comment: I guess because I have like 100 patterns total, so that 102 and 98 +2 complex does not have notable difference. 3.969241142272949 vs 4.059869050979614. And I changed to 2 complex vs 2+2, it is 1.0584890842437744 vs 1.1096751689910889